# Calling a JavaScript function from a URL action

Tags: c#, razor, jquery-select2

I need to get the value of an input and pass that to a select2 to get suggestions. How can I call a JavaScript function from a URL action

```
@* Name *@
<input id="Name" name="AccountName" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" data-url="@Url.Action("*********", "******")" data-urlonselect="@Url.Action("*****", "*******")">

@* Group / HQ *@
@Html.Select2Ajax("newGroup", Url.Action("******", "****", new { valuefromInput = MyFunction(); }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Select2, so there may be some functionality in there that I am unaware of. With that said, the Url.Action() is question is a standard part of the ASP.NET MC framework and I feel relatively comfortable with answering based on that.

Url.Action is a sever side razor directive. That means that all the processing happens on the webserver at the time of the request. It is not, nor can it be, aware of the JavaScript that may execute in the future.

My recommendation would be to create a hidden input, or a non-visible div, and store the output of Url.Action in that container, using a recognizable placeholder for your input value, say "-12."  Then, in your javascript that is responding to the changes to the input, you can dynamically replace the place holder with its actual value and set that property accordingly on the select box. You may or may not need to re-initialize your Select2 drop down in with each call.

At least, that is why I would try. Hope this helps! =)

Comment: When the user fills `input id="Name"` I want to pass that value to the URL action. This is inside a form that doesn't get submitted until everything has been filled out first. I want to pass the value from the `input` to the `Select2Ajax` to get group suggestions based on the value entered in the `input`.  [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Ht4IpkZ.png)